# Show CSS created from Less.js

Tags: css, less

Is it possible to display the CSS that Less.js generates?

I have the following page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Less</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/less" href="test.less">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            less = {
                env: "development", // or "production"
                async: false,       // load imports async
                fileAsync: false,   // load imports async when in a page under
                                    // a file protocol
                poll: 1000,         // when in watch mode, time in ms between polls
                functions: {},      // user functions, keyed by name
                dumpLineNumbers: "comments", // or "mediaQuery" or "all"
                relativeUrls: false,// whether to adjust url's to be relative
                                    // if false, url's are already relative to the
                                    // entry less file
                rootpath: ":/a.com/"// a path to add on to the start of every url
                                    //resource
            };
        </script>
        <script src="less-1.5.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="default">

        <script>

            console.log(less);

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS is working fine, but I want to see what the **'actual'** generated CSS file looks like. I can't see anything in the object `less` that seems to contain it...

Comment: Would using a pre-processor be a possibility ? I mean you could process `less` file on your local machine to see it, and either put the generated CSS online, either keep on "compiling" it client-side.

Comment: I will be doing. I just want to see it with the Less.js version that's all.

Comment: I may be missing something, but aren't you suppose to do some kind of action to initiate client-side "compilation" ? Or is it done automatically upon inserting the less.js file ? Cause your less object looks just like settings...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [LESS - The dynamic stylesheet language.](http://lesscss.org/)

> **Debugging**
>   It is possible to output rules in your CSS which allow tools to locate the source of the rule.
>   Either specify the option dumpLineNumbers as above or add !dumpLineNumbers:mediaQuery to the url.
>   You can use the “comments” option with FireLESS and the “mediaQuery” option with FireBug/Chrome dev tools (it is identical to the SCSS media query debugging format).

A quick glance through https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/dist/less-1.5.1.js shows `function createCSS(styles, sheet, lastModified)` in line 6344. From this function, I would say less creates a `style` element, where the resulting CSS is placed. So, something like this might work

```js
var css = $('style').text();
console.log(css);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5WtNV/)

Comment: Boom :) Thanks that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Use [vLESSlook](https://github.com/valsorym/django-vlesslook/tree/master/vlesslook/static/vlesslook) tool (js/vlesslook.js and css/vlesslook.css). See [readme](https://github.com/valsorym/django-vlesslook) - this not only for Python / Django -  JavaScript and CSS you can use anywhere..

Answer (score 0):

Read the Browser Options
http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage

```
<script>
  less = {
    env: "development",
    async: false,
    fileAsync: false,
    poll: 1000,
    functions: {},
    dumpLineNumbers: "comments",
    relativeUrls: false,
    rootpath: ":/a.com/"
  };
</script>
<script src="less.js"></script>
```

Make sure the `dumpLineNumbers` is set to `"comments",`

Open the DOM explorer of your browser(In my case Firefox -> FireBug) and in `<head>` look for `<style id="less:User...." >`. There is your CSS with comments, lines and files where the generated CSS rules come from.